# Neo4J REST API's

Tags: neo4j

I need some conceptual understanding of Neo4j REST api's usage. I went through the tutorial of neo4j RESt api and got some idea. So is it like these REST api's are used only to CREATE nodes and Relationships and also to fetch data from the neo4j graph database? So can you give me one example/scenario where and how these neo4j REST api's are used?

Thanks,
Shree

Answer (score 2):

Historically the very granular REST API calls for e.g. creating nodes, setting properties were there before Cypher was established. Cypher is a way more concise and compact way to query and modify the graph  compared to the granular REST calls. These days you typically use `Cypher` over the [transactional http endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html).

For some usage examples refer to the manual as well.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. You mean now a days in most of the places Cypher is used instead of Neo4j REST api's for crating nodes and relationships . But if i want to connect to neo4j database from other application , then how can i do it. In that case i should go for REST Api's right or do i have any other alternative in neo4J?

Comment: Exactly, unless you have good reason, Cypher is the way to go for most applications. Your application sends a Cypher query/command wrapped in JSON over the transactional HTTP endpoint to the Neo4j server. The response of the query is returned in JSON back.